# how to group by from different table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

Table A having ID and UnitCost column

```
    ID           UnitCost
    1            10.00
    2            5.00
    3            1.00
```

Table B having LotID and ID which is a foreign key to Table A

```
    LotID         ID From Table A
    A1            1
    A2            1
    A2            2
    A2            2
    A3            3
```

Desired Output:

```
    LotID         Total
    A1            10.00
    A2            20.00
    A3            1.00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL GROUP BY multiple columns from different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564558/mysql-group-by-multiple-columns-from-different-tables)

Comment: Can you post what you have tried till now?

Comment: i have no idea,  Im just beginner in mysql? do you have any idea? pls help me!

Comment: select sum(table_a.unicat) as toral from  table_a join table_b on table_a.ID = table_b.ID group_by table_b.LotID ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and then sum up the unit cost value. Here is the query:

```
SELECT b.LotID, SUM(a.UnitCost) AS Total
FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY b.LotID
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to `JOIN` the two tables using `MYSQL JOIN` then you need to group the LotID then `sum` will be sum the unicast values like this

```
select table_b.LoatID , sum(table_a.UnitCast) as total 
from table_a join table_b 
on table_a.ID = table_b.ID 
group_by table_b.LotID ;
```

1) [Mysql JOIN Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

2) [Mysql group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html)